# Powerpoint edit-restrict to Comments only

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to find a way to restrict access to a set of Powerpoint slides to allow Comments only.

Word has this functionality built-in but Powerpoint does not seem to have this.

No code thought of at present

Looked at password protection of Powerpoint files

Comment: The Excel folks sometimes create what're called "dictator app", code that removes all of the normal Excel UI and replaces it with only the functions the author wants the users to have. Even if that were possible in PPT (may or may not be) it'd probably be impossible to override all of the keyboard shortcuts. It might be simpler to provide the same functionality in a dedicated app that displays images of the slides from the PPT presentation and allows for entering comments; this could probably be done in such a way that the app passes comments back into the password protected source PPT

Comment: Another thought: save the presentation as a Picture Presentation.  This converts all of the slide content to an image, so it's not editable. Recipients can add comments (and other content/shapes) but can't alter the content from the original.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll try that!